# fileURLWithPath is getting nil for AVPlayerController

Tags: ios, swift2, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm trying to play a video with AVPlayer but getting error while giving pathForResource. Tried all possible ways of wrapping optional values but not succeed. Any one can help me out.

```
    let userdefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let mediaPath = userdefault.URLForKey("VideoPath")
    print(mediaPath)

    let movieString = mediaPath!.path
    let pathExtension = mediaPath!.pathExtension



    let newPath = movieString!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(".\(pathExtension)", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    print(newPath)
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(newPath, ofType: ".\(pathExtension)")

    print(path)

    if let pathString = path {
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathString)
        myplayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        myplayer.play()
    }
    else {
        print("Oooopppsss, something wrong when playing video")
    }
```

Comment: where your video is stored in bundle or in document directory?

Comment: from document directory

Comment: then why are you using NSBundle.mainBundle()

Comment: Oopss i'm feel like dumb..:D Thanks sid

Comment: Your welcome Princes